# SQL about join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

There are 2 tables - table1 and table2
I would like to have the number of counts of the grade that val in the corresponding range

table1

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ val ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ 80  ║
║  2 ║ 75  ║
║  3 ║ 72  ║
║  4 ║ 85  ║
║  5 ║ 70  ║
║  6 ║ 80  ║
║  7 ║ 76  ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

table2

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ grade ║ boundary ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║  A    ║ 85       ║
║  B    ║ 80       ║
║  C    ║ 75       ║
║  D    ║ 70       ║
║  E    ║ 65       ║
║  F    ║  0       ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```

How can I have the result like:

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ grade ║ total  ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║  A    ║ 1      ║
║  B    ║ 2      ║
║  C    ║ 2      ║
║  D    ║ 2      ║
║  E    ║ 0      ║
║  F    ║ 0      ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

I used to do it using PHP, but I want to do it using SQL only
I not familiar with complicated join statement.

Comment: Can you please post what SQL you have tried already so that we can help you find what isn't working? If you are struggling with JOINs in general, take a look through [the w3schools page on this topic](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is very doable. Personally I'd change the table2 structure to include upper and lower limits.

Assuming you can't do that this solution simulates that with a CTE which allows direct bounding. I've also used a subquery to still show the grades with no population - if you don't care about rows with zero records you can ignore this bit.

This is SQL Server Syntax (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1e9b/1) but the principle will work should work fine with most RDBMS' :) Enjoy

```
--setup
create table scores (

  id integer,
  val integer
  );

create table boundaries (

  grade varchar(max),
  boundary integer
  );

INSERT INTO scores values (1,80);
INSERT INTO scores values (2,75);
INSERT INTO scores values (3,72);
INSERT INTO scores values (4,85);
INSERT INTO scores values (5,70);
INSERT INTO scores values (6,80);
INSERT INTO scores values (7,76);

INSERT INTO boundaries values ('A',85);
INSERT INTO boundaries values ('B',80);
INSERT INTO boundaries values ('C',75);
INSERT INTO boundaries values ('D',70);
INSERT INTO boundaries values ('E',65);
INSERT INTO boundaries values ('F',0);

--query
with rangesCTE as (
SELECT 
  grade
  , boundary as lowerBoundary
  , coalesce (LAG (boundary,1) OVER (ORDER BY boundary desc),100) AS higherBoundary
FROM boundaries)

select 
  boundaries.grade
  , coalesce (sq.total,0) as total
from boundaries 
left join (
  select 
    rangesCTE.grade as grade
    , count(*) as total
  from scores
  left join rangesCTE on scores.val >= rangesCTE.lowerBoundary and scores.val < rangesCTE.higherBoundary
  group by rangesCTE.grade
) sq on boundaries.grade = sq.grade
```

Comment: Finally, I added the column of upper_boundary
Although Ronald's solution works fine, the processing time is so slow.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help :) if you ended up using this feel free to upvote or accept my answer!  I liked Ronald's answer but there are times where more code and a better setup means better performance/results!

Comment: But CTE is only supported in MySql 8.0 and I was not letting myself make any assumption about CTE availability.

Comment: Good point Ronald - either way I think the poster is correct to change the DDL (assuming he can!) it's very much the fastest way here - certainly faster than lead/lag. Of course you don't really need a CTE you can use a subquery of course too but anything requiring compute is slower than anything only requiring read :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select table2.grade, ifnull(total, 0) as total from table2 left join (
    select grade, count(*) as total from (
        select table2.grade from table1 join table2
        on table2.boundary = (select max(boundary) from table2 where boundary <= table1.val)
    ) sq
    group by grade
) sq on table2.grade = sq.grade
order by grade;
```

[See DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v99Fc91iPgC5bmYYsks9Xa/0)

Comment: I like this answer too!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the simple right join.

```
SELECT t2.grade,count(t1.val) FROM table1 t1
right join table2 t2
on t1.val=t2.boundary
GROUP by t2.grade,t1.val
order by t2.grade ASC
```

1- Below code will just join the table and select all columns.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
right  join table2 t2
on t1.val=t2.boundary
```

[image]

2- Adding groupby will group the element on grade and count the repeated data.

```
SELECT t2.grade,count(t1.val) FROM table1 t1
right join table2 t2
on t1.val=t2.boundary
GROUP by t2.grade,t1.val
order by t2.grade ASC
```

Comment: With that code, how will row with id 3 or 7 from table1 be counted?

Comment: This code can't work - a direct match between values and ranges is possible but cannot be expected.